# How to calculate the variance of a two-particle distribution function?

Tags: variance

I have calculated a two-particle distribution function called $f(r)$ where $r$ is the distance between of two particle (also there are three parameters,$\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ in its formula which I should calculate $f(r)$ for different values of them). I have been asked: Calculate the average value of $r$ and the variance of distribution which shows the width of distribution.
So I tried this (according to standard formula for variance of continuous variable in Wiki):
$$
\operatorname{Var}(r)=\int_0^{\infty}r^2 f(r)\,\mathrm dr-\biggl(\int_0^{\infty}r f(r)\,\mathrm dr \biggr)^2
$$
but it returns negative value for some parameters. Am I wrong? If Yes how can I calculate what I was asked?

Comment: There's no way for that to actually be negative. Are you sure $f$ is actually a density i.e. $\int_0^\infty f(r) dr = 1$ and $f(r) \geq 0$? (Often in physics we obtain functions which are proportional to densities but aren't normalized.)

Comment: yes, it yields 1 and is greater than 0

Comment: Then something went awry in your computation.

Comment: I have included $N^2$, normalization constant in its formula

Comment: Maybe discuss how you're doing the integration? I assume it's numerically, and in this case you could have issues depending on how the integrals are actually evaluated. This could be helped by considering $\int_0^\infty \left ( r - \int_0^\infty s f(s) ds \right )^2 f(r) dr$ instead, since this will be "automatically" nonnegative.

Comment: @Ian Thanks a lot, I found something strange! I had checked for some parameters that integration over $f(r)$ must yield 1, but Now I checked it where the negative value for variance is obtained and it was a very very negative value!! So my formula is a correct answer for what I was asked?

Comment: Yes, although again if you do the two integrals using different quadrature rules or using quadrature rules with negative weights then it may potentially still give an erroneous negative value.

Comment: @Ian Do you mean that it is more reliable to use the formula you suggested instead of mine?

Comment: @Ian Haha! you know the main problem was that I should have used numerical integration `NIntegrate` instead of analytical integration in Mathematica. Now all results are OK.